Geodesics in terms of connections?
I am trying to better understand how geodesics and connections are related beyond the usual case of Riemannian manifolds. In particular, I am wondering:

If every connection allow to define geodesics?
If that's the case, then how the two are related in the most general sense?
If that's not the case, then what are additional requirements on connections that allow to define geodesics?

I am in particular thinking about Ehresmann connection, Cartan connection, Gauss–Manin connection, Connes connection (non-commutative geometry)... In the general sense I am trying to understand how connections and geodesics are related (for example if there is a mathematical expression that links the two in all cases).

Well it depends on what you'd want 'geodesics' to be. Already in the Riemannian case there is a distinction to be made:
If you have a (say smooth) manifold with connection $(M,\nabla)$, this gives you a notion of 'straight curves'. Those are just the autoparallely transported curves, i.e. curves $\gamma$ in $M$ such that (by abusing notation)
$$
\nabla_{\dot\gamma}\dot\gamma=0.
$$
In a smooth coordinate chart $(U,x^1,\dots,x^n)$ this equation reads
$$
\ddot\gamma^k+\Gamma^{k}{}_{ij}\dot\gamma^i\dot\gamma^j=0,
$$
where $\gamma^j=x^j\circ \gamma$ and $\Gamma^{k}_{\; ij}$ are the connection coefficient functions.
Geodesics on the other hand are in some sense the 'shortest' (as opposed to the 'straight') curves. More precisely they are locally distance-minimizing and parametrized proportionally to arc-length. Of course you will need a notion of distance and length, which a metric $g$ on $M$ will provide. In a smooth coordinate chart $(U,x^1,\dots,x^n)$ a curve $\gamma$ is a geodesic if and only if
$$
\ddot\gamma^i+\frac 12 g^{im}\left(\partial_l g_{mk}+\partial_k g_{ml}-\partial_m g_{kl}\right)\dot\gamma^k\dot\gamma^l=0.
$$
One of course immediately recognizes the similarity between the geodesic equation and the autoparallel equation. Defining
$$
\Gamma^{i}{}_{kl}:=\frac 12 g^{im}\left(\partial_l g_{mk}+\partial_k g_{ml}-\partial_m g_{kl}\right)
$$
for a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ indeed induces a connection $\nabla$ on $M$ (the Levi-Civita connection) and this choice for $\nabla$ basically identifies the 'straight curves' with the 'shortest curves'.
This shows: In general a metric allows for the definition of geodesics and also the definition of autoparallely transported curves. On the other hand a generic connection $\nabla$ does not allow for the definition of geodesics. In short: A connection gives the manifold 'shape', while a metric further gives it 'size'.

I disagree. The typical definition of a geodesic in differential geometry — even in elementary undergraduate courses — is given in the presence of a connection, and it specializes to the Riemannian situation, wherein we then deduce (prove) that the curves are locally distance-minimizing.

@TedShifrin Fair enough. That's why I started my answer with "Well it depends on what you'd want 'geodesics' to be". If one wants the 'shortest curves' definition, a connection is not enough. If that's not what one's after, however, of course a connection suffices.
